# DependencyProperties with Bools: False Causes Event not to Fire

Tags: events, xaml, user-controls, windows-runtime

So I have created a bool dependency property for my xaml user control. However when the value is set to false in xaml, it does not fire the event when it is set to true in xaml it does. How can I get it to fire the event no matter what?

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AvailableProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Available", typeof(bool), typeof(DetailPannel),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, onAvailablePropertyChanged));

public bool Available
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(AvailableProperty);  }
    set { SetValue(AvailableProperty, value); }
}

private async static void onAvailablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,   DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = d as DetailPannel;
    bool avaible = (bool.Parse(e.NewValue.ToString())); 
    if(avaible == false )
    {            
        obj.PreviewImage.Source = await ConvertToGreyscale(obj.PreviewImage);
        obj.StateRelatedImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///icon.png")); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value `null` is not valid for a bool property. Change your PropertyMetadata to specify either `false` or `true` as default value:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AvailableProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Available", typeof(bool), typeof(DetailPannel),
    new PropertyMetadata(false, onAvailablePropertyChanged));
```

Also the code in your PropertyChanged handler looks suspicious. Don't use `bool.Parse`, but just cast `e.NewValue` to `bool`:

```
private async static void onAvailablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = d as DetailPannel;
    var available = (bool)e.NewValue; 

    if (!available)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```